# Save data to CSV with Python - will save only 1 row

Tags: python, sql, csv

I have simple Python script to save data to CSV file

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', db="", user='', passwd='')

cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table"

try:
    cursor.execute(sql)

    with open('MyFile.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = ['Col1_Name', 'Col2_Name', 'Col3_Name', 'Combined_Col']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()

        results = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in results:
           col1 = row[0]
           col2 = row[1]
           col3 = row[2]
           col4 = row[3]
           col5 = row[4]

           combinedColumns = "%s (count: %s)" % (col4, col5)

           writer.writerow({'Col1_Name': col1, 'Col2_Name' : col2, 'Col3_Name': col3, 'Combined_Col': combinedColumns})

except:
    print("Error: unable to fetch data")

db.close()

print("DONE!")
```

but it will save only one row.

What I have missed?

Comment: please share the error log

Comment: try importing sys

Comment: @ShrikantShete I have updated OP. Got data saved but only 1 row

Comment: Don't use a generic try/except; It hides your error, making it harder to debug the code. Remove the try/except and you will see the real error

Comment: @nosklo Yeah, I have got to the point where I can save data but will store only 1 row

Comment: @JackTheKnife my point still stands, if you have a generic try/except you're getting a generic "unable to fetch data" instead of the real error. Never do a generic try/except.

Comment: Yes, I have removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', db="", user='', passwd='')

cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table"

try:
    cursor.execute(sql)

    with open('MyFile.csv', mode='w', newlines='') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = ['Col1_Name', 'Col2_Name', 'Col3_Name', 'Combined_Col']
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

        writer.writerow(fieldnames)

        results = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in results:
           col1 = row[0]
           col2 = row[1]
           col3 = row[2]
           col4 = row[3]
           col5 = row[4]

           combinedColumns = "%s (count: %s)" % (col4, col5)

           writer.writerow(row)

except:
    print("Error: unable to fetch data")

db.close()

print("DONE!")
```

Comment: It will fail on that line now.

Comment: my bad, i miss the paramerts

Comment: According to the [`csv` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer), you must open the file with `newlines=''` in order for it to add new lines properly:  `with open('MyFile.csv', mode='w', newlines='') as csv_file:`